# Why is '\t', returned from "backtick" call, expanded to tabulator? What all characters are expanded?

Tags: perl, bash

If I run a simple perl script like this (on linux, with bash),

```
$to_run = q(echo '\t');
$res = `$to_run`;
print $res
```

I would expect that `\t` will be printed - that is, the backslash character and "t" character. Indeed, if I run just in bash

```
echo '\t'
```

I see `\t`. However, the perl script prints the tabulator.

Why is the tabulator expanded in `$res`? What all characters are expanded like that? And, most importantly, how do I stop it from expanding?

Comment: The code you posted does print slash-t, not a tab.

Comment: Interesting. It prints a tab for me.

Comment: Did you actually run the code you posted, cause the code you ran originally didn't compile. It's far more likely your problem is that you used `\t` in the backticks or in `qq` instead of in `q`. Or perhaps the command was `echo \t` rather than `echo '\t'`.

Comment: Yes, I did. Right now again. I know it didn't compile (the ending backtick, thanks for spotting that) because I tried to simplify the code I had, but if I run the version in the question letter by letter, it still prints a tabulator. I run it in bash, on gentoo linux (and now debian, too).

Comment: `perl -v` says my perl version is v5.10.1, if that helps.

Comment: If that's your code, then your `echo` that's weird. What's your OS?

Comment: gentoo linux, debian linux, it does that in both.

Comment: OK, this is becoming ridiculous. Here you have a screenshot. http://imgur.com/mGCM6aH I don't know if I proved my worth to you now.

Comment: wow, you have the weirdest system. I wonder what got changed. Is `/bin/sh` still `bash`? (`/bin/sh --version`)

Comment: Thanks for the tip where to look at; nope, apparently, on the debian and ubuntu, `/bin/sh` is a symlink to `/bin/dash`, Debian's own shell (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_Almquist_shell ). Not sure about the Gentoo system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Backticks are evaluated using `/bin/sh`, regardless of whatever shell you may want to use, and it's the [POSIX XSI-conformant version of `echo` implemented by `sh`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/echo.html) that's converting `\t` to a tab.  Try it out yourself by running `echo '\t'` inside `sh`.

For avoiding this behavior, trying using `printf '%s\n'` instead of `echo` in backticks.